# Is there an algorithm for a number line from $0$ to $n$

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Where $n + 1 = 0$ 
and $0 - 1 = n$?

The $n + 1 = 0$ case can be achieved by using the modulus operator, but I can't figure out how to treat the $0 - 1 = n$ case.

Answer (score 3):

For $a,b \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$, subtraction is given by
$$
a - b = [a + (n+1-b)] \bmod{(n+1)}.
$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: But you should be careful when implementing it using a programming language. Python and Ruby will evaluate (0 - 20) % 13 as 6 while C++ will output -7.

Comment: @fade2black Fortunately, this formula only involves non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply compute $(a - b) \bmod{(n+1)}$. But you should also be aware of the [least positive remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) and the [least absolute remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder).
Some libraries/languages may output the least positive remainder (for example Ruby and Python), while others may output the least absolute remainder [like in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values). In the later case if the remainder is negative you simply add it to $n+1$.